# owlCarousel CSS3 Transitions Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, owl-carousel

Why Owl Carousel Css3 Transitions not working?

recently i got this issue in my website.But when i visited their website it's also not working.anyone know what's this issue?

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked is working fine.Check to see if you have not disabled javascript by mistake on your browser.

Also check on other browsers to see if the same issue arrises.

Answer (score 0):

/* fade */

```
 ...
   -webkit-animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
 ...
```

"... it's just working in FireFox and Safari. 
For some reason Chrome doesn't add the class ".owl-fade-out" in the "div.owl-item" ..."

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing